# Angular 8 - Form Group Values are always empty

Tags: angular8

Am new to angular and am starting off with a simple login form. However the form values are always showing up as empty - even if values have been entered before form submission.

I have created a login component which is imported in app module. The page comes up, but the submission does not carry any values. I have removed all Angular validation checks for debugging but the values received in my onsubmit function are still empty.

I have pasted the component code.Below.

login.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">  
<div class="form-group" >
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" formcontrolname="username" 
    placeholder="Email Id" required autofocus/><br/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" formcontrolname="password" placeholder="Password" required/><br/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <button>Login</button>
  <a href="/public/register" class="btn" >Register</a>
</div>
```

app.component

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
     imports:      [ BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule, 
       ReactiveFormsModule ],
     declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, LoginComponent ],
     bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

login.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


 @Component({
   selector: 'app-login',
   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
 })
 export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   loginForm: FormGroup;
   submitted = false;
   returnUrl = '';

   constructor(
     private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
     private router: Router
   ) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group ({
        username: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
 get user() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

 onSubmit() {
 // stop if form is invalid
 /*  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
   console.log("Returning");
   return;
  } */
  this.submitted = true;

  console.log('login values:');
  console.log(this.user.username.value, this.user.password.value);

  this.returnUrl='/home';
  // this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
get user() { return this.loginForm.value; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Knew it would be something super silly and trivial - turned out to be a case sensitivity problem issue on my end. Changed 'formcontrolname' to 'formControlName' and it started working! Duh!